# Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ &lt;required&gt; $card_id ]] in class

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to use larvel to show a specific swipe depending on the card_id that is entered. Current card_id is not the serial ID but is still a unique id binded to every user, so the serial id is just 1,2,3,4,5 and the card_id will be: 321a4s and can have multiple id's attached to it, below is my current code for the endpoint:
Controller

```
public function show($card_id)
    {
        $swipe = Swipe::find($card_id);
        //Verify swipe exists
        if(!$swipe){return response("ID Not Found", 404);}
        return $swipe;
    }
```

swipe.php

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'mask_id';
  protected $table = 'swipe';

  protected $fillable = [
        'card_id',
    ];
```

Why am i still getting this error? And what is the best solution going forward?

Comment: does the route that points to this action have a route parameter defined? that `$card_id` has to mean something

Comment: The route to the show function is just
$router->get('/swipe/{card_id}', 'SwipeController@show');
If i set the $card_id as the primary key it works, but $card_id also needs to be a fillable so when i set it to a primary key everytime i create a new sipe $card_id is set to 0.